# Testing if certain points affect the time-series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, hypothesis-testing, change-point

I have a time series that describes the popularity of a product. I want to test if, when someone popular ( on social media ) publishes about the product ( positively or negatively ) it causes a "changepoint" in the time series ( high growth or severe drop ).

[image]

in red, the timestamps where a popular influencer published the product.

I'm trying to use a change point algorithm detection, and check the similarity between the indexes, get a certain % to validate my hypothesis.

Am I on the right path? is there any other methods, libraries...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it always setup like this or are there times when there are multiple tweets in one time series?  If it is always inspecting one tweet and it's impact then I second @Michael Grogan for looking at CausualImpact.

Comment: @Tylerr a point might have multiple tweets from popular influencers since i'm using a weekly aggregation

Answer (score 1):

The [TensorFlow Probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Bayesian_Switchpoint_Analysis#prerequisites) library has a Bayesian Switchpoint Analysis feature which could be of use to you in this case.

As an example, here is a graph of [Wikipedia](https://pageviews.toolforge.org/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&redirects=0&start=2019-06-13&end=2020-07-03&pages=Vacation) page views for the term "vacation" from June 2019 to July 2020.

[image: Vacation page views]

We can see that after sometime after day 400, there is a significant drop-off in search interest for this term - which coincides with the period in March when COVID-19 was declared a global pandemic.

Using TF Probability, Bayesian analysis can be used to identify the period with the highest probability of a switchpoint being present. In this case, it occurs sometime after day 400.

[image: bayesian switchpoint analysis]

One other option could be to use the [CausalImpact](https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html) package, whereby one could test if a social media post makes a difference to product popularity by using a non-related product which is not affected by social media as a control variable.

Indeed, using both methods would provide more credence to your findings. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Michael, is it applicable to detect multiple change points?

Comment: Yes, this can be done. https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Multiple_changepoint_detection_and_Bayesian_model_selection